# Get info about which groups didn't matched

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to retrieve information about what groups haven't been matched?
In my regex I have two groups:  `(\d+)-(\w+)`.

I would like to be able to retrieve information about what group didn't matched. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(\d+)?-(\w+)?` regex instead. Both groups are declared optional which means that it matches as soon as a hyphen is found. After using `Matcher.matches()` or `Matcher.find()` you can call `Matcher.group(n)` to determine which groups have matched. A group that has not been matched will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `pat` variable contains a string (with capturing groups)
and `txt` the text to search.

After you execute e.g.:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher m = r.matcher(txt);
```

You can use `m.group(1)` to retrieve the 1st capturing group,
`m.group(2)` for the 2nd and so on.

So just read the required capturing group and check whether it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can check group by group and check if not `null`, for example :

```
String input = "your input";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)-(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

List<String> reslt = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    //check first group
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("match");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not match");
    }
    //check second group
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("match");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not match");
    }
}
```